# Mysql query using GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Using following mysql query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS time,report,count(ip) AS countip FROM asn_data WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') > '2012-10-31' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d'),report;
```

I got following output:

```
+------------+---------------+---------+
| time       | report        | countip |
+------------+---------------+---------+
| 2012-11-01 | bots          |      76 |
| 2012-11-01 | openresolvers |      97 |
| 2012-11-01 | proxy         |      24 |
| 2012-11-01 | scanners      |       4 |
| 2012-11-01 | spam          |     881 |
| 2012-11-02 | bots          |     142 |
| 2012-11-02 | proxy         |      22 |
| 2012-11-02 | spam          |     667 |
| 2012-11-03 | proxy         |       1 |
+------------+---------------+---------+
```

What will be the query to get the following output:

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+------+
| time       | bots        | openresolvers | Proxy | scanners | spam |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+------+
| 2012-11-01 | 76          | 97            | 24    | 4        | 881  |
| 2012-11-02 | 142         | 0             | 22    | 0        | 667  |
| 2012-11-03 | 0           | 0             | 1     | 0        | 0    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------+----------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   DATE(time)                  AS time,
         SUM(report='bots'         ) AS bots,
         SUM(report='openresolvers') AS openresolvers,
         SUM(report='proxy'        ) AS Proxy,
         SUM(report='scanners'     ) AS scanners,
         SUM(report='spam'         ) AS spam
FROM     asn_data
WHERE    time > '2012-10-31'
GROUP BY DATE(time)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/522f1/6/0).

If you wish to exclude records where `ip IS NULL`, add `AND ip IS NOT NULL` into each of the `SUM()` functions.

Comment: Fixed the typo error(field separator), How can you be sure that the ip column doesn't exist in the table ???  And again, your answer have the same logic of my answer and changes only the form ...

Comment: and if the ip field is null ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a group concat here, you need to pivot the resultset, try in this way :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') AS time,
SUM(CASE WHEN report = 'bots' THEN ipc ELSE 0 END) AS bots,
SUM(CASE WHEN report = 'openresolvers' THEN ipc ELSE 0 END) AS openresolvers,
SUM(CASE WHEN report = 'Proxy' THEN ipc ELSE 0 END) AS Proxy,
SUM(CASE WHEN report = 'scanners' THEN ipc ELSE 0 END) AS scanners,
SUM(CASE WHEN report = 'spam' THEN ipc ELSE 0 END) AS spam
FROM (
SELECT count(ip) AS ipc, report, DATE(time) as time 
FROM  asn_data 
GROUP BY report, DATE(time)) i
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d') > '2012-10-31'
GROUP BY time;
```

Comment: This answer still attempts to aggregate twice, which will result in [Invalid use of group function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_invalid_group_func_use).

Comment: Hi @aleroot: I am getting syntax error. You can try running the code in following schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/522f1/2

Comment: @FakrulAlam see the updated answer and the working SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/522f1/27 , i haven't tried the query before, sorry